# billboard.js: The types of 'axis.x.type' are incompatible between these types

Tags: javascript, typescript, billboard.js, es6-modules

```
axis: {
    x: {
      type: "category"
    }
  },
```

I got error:

```
The types of 'axis.x.type' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"category" | "indexed" | "log" | "timeseries"'
```

I cannot find how i can init type with another way. Could you please help me?

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast category as `const` to notify ts `"category"` is one of the const types of `"category" | "indexed" | "log" | "timeseries"` in x axis type.

```
const options = {
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: "category" as const,
    },
  },
};
```